# how to update values in tic tac toe board

Tags: python, flask

I made tic tac toe 3x3 board. The board is 2d list of session object, when i try to update the value of the 2d list its always puts
values on 0x0 square. always!

Not really sure how to solve this, only 1 month that i learn python and flask. So its beyond me. I tried different ways how to
     update board, but i can't solve this problem

Not sure this problem is coming because I iterate in bad way or my HTML is not good, but i don't think that i can solve this problem
alone, if anyone could help me i would be very grateful

```py
    @app.route("/")
    def index():
        if "lenta" not in session:
            session["lenta"] = [[None, None, None], [None, None, None], [None, None, None]]
            session["move"] = "X"

        return render_template("game.html", game=session["lenta"], move=session["move"])


    @app.route("/play/<int:row>/<int:col>")
    def play(row, col):
        for i in session["lenta"]:
            for j, h in enumerate(i):
                i[j] = row, col
                return redirect(url_for("index"))
```

HTML portion of code works fine, it returns the the position of tile if i click on it, but only its square 0x0

```
 <table>
        {% for i in range(3) %}
            <tr>
                {% for j in range(3) %}
                    <td>
                        {% if game[i][j] %}
                            {{ game[i][j] }}
                        {% else %}
                            <a href="{{url_for('play', row=i, col=j)}}">Place {{ move }}</a>
                        {% endif %}
                    </td>
                {% endfor %}
            </tr>
        {% endfor %}
    </table>
```

[the result of runing code](https://i.stack.imgur.com/f7xUB.png)

I would like that if you click on the tile it would print coordinates of the square in the square that i click.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is in your `play` method, you return on the first iteration of the loop

```
@app.route("/play/<int:row>/<int:col>")
def play(row, col):
    for i in session["lenta"]:
        for j, h in enumerate(i):
            # On the first iteration of the loops you are returning
            # when i is the first row and j is 0
            i[j] = row, col # only ever updating 0, 0
            return redirect(url_for("index"))
```

Looks like you want to update the matching row and column

```
@app.route("/play/<int:row>/<int:col>")
def play(row, col):
    session["lenta"][row][col] = row, col
    return redirect(url_for("index"))
```

You should add some bounds checking here, a try/except would be the first step

Comment: Ya it worked Thanks. Im a beginner in programing. i tried something very similar, but, how session["lenta"][row][col], know that 1 value is row and second is col? these values coming from HTML.